# How to set up Apache, MySQL Servers (Ubuntu 12.04 LST)

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, xampp

I am hoping to get guidance on using Apache and MySQL servers on Ubuntu 12.04. I am new to Linux, and am trying to setup a "Localhost" dynamic for basic website design.

In windows - I had used a simple free utiliy called XAMPP which installed  Apache, MySQL, and a Localhost folder for my wesite work to reside.  Though basic, this XAMPP install worked pretty good for my needs. Is there some stable utility in the Ubuntu depositories that will give me Apache and MySQL servers with a" htdocs(localhost)" folder where I can put websites that are under construction - (something similar to XAMPP) ?
If not - instruction on how to manually configure this dynamic would be much appreciated.

Also, would welcome suggestions as to which is better. Thanks.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install tasksel && tasksel` See the menu ;)

Comment: hmm..this should be in the answer section, not in comment.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. LAMP means "Linux Apache MySQL, PHP".

http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies

Answer (score 0):

LAMPP/XAMPP is probably also available for Linux.

But you can also install all things individually from the repositories (it's just a little bit harder). 
To install Apache, PHP, MySQL and phpMyAdmin, run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server mysql-client php5 php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5 phpmyadmin
```

You could also use Synaptic Package Manager to install these packages (it's graphical and easy to use). You can find it in the Software Center (if not installed already).

After that, open your browser and point it to **localhost** to see if Apache is working and **localhost/phpmyadmin** to see if phpMyAdmin is working. Apache should have started automatically.

You can start/stop/restart the Apache server by using the commands (respectively):

```
sudo service apache2 start
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The folder where the websites (html files, php files, etc.) should go is **/var/www**.
Note that you can't create/delete files in that folder directly (because you don't have write access).
An easy solution is to create a folder for each website as **root** and set yourself as owner:

```
sudo mkdir "/var/www/SITE_NAME"
sudo chown YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_USERNAME "/var/www/SITE_NAME"
```

Change **SITE_NAME** to the name of the folder you want and **YOUR_USERNAME** to your username.
After that you should be able to do everything inside the folder you created.
Then you would access the website in the browser through the URL **localhost/SITE_NAME**.